# MayaVi contour3d after coordinate transformation

Tags: python, plot, mayavi

I have a 3D scalar field mesh given in non-cartesian coordinate system.
After coordinate transformation back to conventional cartesian coordinates
`mlab.contour3d` displays wrong result, while `mlab.points3d` works as expected. How can I view isosurfaces of given mesh in different coordinate systems?

This is my code

```py
import os
import numpy as np
# fix incorrect order in foregroud objects
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'
from mayavi import mlab


def plot_cell(cell, mlab):
    for nr, i in enumerate(cell):
        coord = np.zeros((4, 3), dtype=float)
        coord[1] = i
        for nr2, j in enumerate(cell):
            if nr == nr2:
                continue

            coord[2] = i + j
            for nr3, k in enumerate(cell):
                if nr3 == nr or nr3 == nr2:
                    continue
                coord[3] = i + j + k
                mlab.plot3d(*coord.T, color=(0, 0, 0), line_width=0.01)

# generate data in non-cartesian coordinate system
scaled_coord = [np.linspace(0, 1, 20, endpoint=False) for i in range(3)]
XYZ = np.array(np.meshgrid(*scaled_coord, indexing="ij"))
data = np.sin(2*np.pi*XYZ[0])*np.sin(2*np.pi*XYZ[1])*np.sin(2*np.pi*XYZ[2])

plot_cell(np.eye(3), mlab)
mlab.contour3d(*XYZ, data)
mlab.savefig("old_coord.png")
mlab.close()

# transform to cartesian coordinates
cell = np.array(
    [[ 1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
     [-0.5 ,  0.87,  0.  ],
     [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  3.07]])
transformation_matrix = cell.T
XYZ2 = np.einsum('ij,jabc->iabc', transformation_matrix, XYZ)

# plot transformed result
plot_cell(cell, mlab)
mlab.contour3d(*XYZ2, data)
mlab.savefig("new_coord.png")
mlab.close()

# plot points
plot_cell(cell, mlab)
mlab.points3d(*XYZ2, data)
mlab.savefig("new_coord_expected.png")
mlab.close()
```

[image: old coordinate system]
[image: new coordinate system]
[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching [3D Visualization with Mayavi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6OD07Qq2mw&t=7925s) I managed to solve it myself. 
Problem is that `mlab.contour3d` works only with rectilinear grid data (grid generated with `np.meshgrid` or `np.mgrid`). In my case one can use `tvtk.StructuredGrid` object for structured grids which have same topology as
rectilinear grid but nonuniform spacing and directions between points.

This is working code:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
from tvtk.api import tvtk
# fix incorrect order in foregroud objects
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'
from mayavi import mlab


def plot_cell(cell, mlab):
    for nr, i in enumerate(cell):
        coord = np.zeros((4, 3), dtype=float)
        coord[1] = i
        for nr2, j in enumerate(cell):
            if nr == nr2:
                continue

            coord[2] = i + j
            for nr3, k in enumerate(cell):
                if nr3 == nr or nr3 == nr2:
                    continue
                coord[3] = i + j + k
                mlab.plot3d(*coord.T, color=(0, 0, 0), line_width=0.01)


scaled_coord = [np.linspace(0, 1, 20, endpoint=False) for i in range(3)]
ABC = np.array(np.meshgrid(*scaled_coord, indexing="ij"))
data = np.sin(2*np.pi*ABC[0])*np.sin(2*np.pi*ABC[1])*np.sin(2*np.pi*ABC[2])

# transform to cartesian coordinates
cell = np.array(
    [[ 1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
     [-0.5 ,  0.87,  0.  ],
     [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  3.07]])
transformation_matrix = cell.T
x, y, z = np.einsum('ij,jabc->iabc', transformation_matrix, ABC)

def generate_structured_grid(x, y, z, scalars):
    pts = np.empty(z.shape + (3,), dtype=float)
    pts[..., 0] = x
    pts[..., 1] = y
    pts[..., 2] = z

    pts = pts.transpose(2, 1, 0, 3).copy()
    pts.shape = int(pts.size / 3), 3
    scalars = scalars.T.copy()

    sg = tvtk.StructuredGrid(dimensions=x.shape, points=pts)
    sg.point_data.scalars = scalars.ravel()
    sg.point_data.scalars.name = 'scalars'
    return sg

sgrid = generate_structured_grid(x, y, z, data)
src = mlab.pipeline.add_dataset(sgrid)
isosurface = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src)
plot_cell(cell, mlab)
mlab.show()
```